# How to run a shell (.sh) file 20 times parallel to each other in background in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

As I said, I have a script in a file named looper.sh (which will loop for 27 times) and I wanted to run this file 20 times at a time (Simultaneously) like parallelly and that too in the background of ubuntu OS 20.04. I don't want to see the output of the file(not important).

If we run the sh file

`sh looper.sh`

the output is

```
1
2
3
4
5
till 
27
```

so the about output should run 20 times at a time without output.

I wanted to run the  `sh looper.sh` 20 times simultaneously in the background.

Comment: no, I need to test my server I wrote a few calculations in that looper.sh. @user68186 can you do it?

Comment: if possible can you be more specific please, or else keywords to search will help me a lot. thanks @user68186

Comment: @user68186 just to run something in background `screen` is not needed. The OP can simply run the command in background with `&` at the end.

Comment: @raj that works too! :-)

Comment: Try not to run the script as `sh looper.sh` the *shebang* will be interpreted as a comment and effectively ignored. It can create odd behaviors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script below should run `sh looper.sh` 20 times in the background, discarding the output:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while [ $i -lt 20 ]; do
  sh looper.sh > /dev/null &
  i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I have a doubt does this code will run parallelly like it will not care about the first script to finish and then 2nd one starts or 20 times it will start at a time??

Comment: That's what the `&` character at the end of the line is for. It runs the command in background and doesn't wait for it to finish.

Comment: thanks a lot @raj Yes, it is running and I'm able to finish it. Actually, I'm creating a cybersecurity tool and need this link to the performance testing part and thanks for the help. Please share your Github username I will add you as a contribuator. thanks a lot again.

Comment: @user68186 but I start with $i=0, so from 0 to 19 it is exactly 20 times.

Comment: @raj, I realized that after typing the comment and deleted that comment. :-)